# Clicking a button results in exe_bad_action

Tags: ios, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I created a brand new project and created a new view controller with a button in the view.

I am adding the view in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


    BOOL introDisplayed = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kIntroScreenSeenByUser];

    if(introDisplayed)
    {

    }
    else 
    {
        IntroView *introView = [[IntroView alloc] initWithNibName:@"IntroView" bundle:nil];
        [self.window addSubview:introView.view];
    }

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

.h file

```
@interface IntroView : UIViewController 


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *clickMe;
- (IBAction)clicked:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "IntroView.h"

@interface IntroView ()
@end

@implementation IntroView
@synthesize clickMe;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setClickMe:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (IBAction)clicked:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"clicked");
}
@end
```

Clicking on the button results in a EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2 error. Any ideas? I am using ARC.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Created a public property on the application delegate called "introViewController" and changed the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
@synthesize introViewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


    BOOL introDisplayed = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kIntroScreenSeenByUser];

    introViewController = [[IntroView alloc] initWithNibName:@"IntroView" bundle:nil];
    if(introDisplayed)
    {

    }
    else 
    {
        [self.window addSubview:introViewController.view];
    }

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

This solved the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating your IntroView controller, and adding it's view as a subview, but the controller itself is released. I don't think that adding the view controller's view (and then letting ARC discard the controller itself) is an acceptable way to create a view.

Perhaps you could make the IntroView view controller a property of the app delegate class and therefore it won't be released by ARC.

Personally, I don't monkey around with the app delegate's creation of the views and controllers, but rather I let my target settings and my NIBs dictate that. I presume you're doing this because you want to have some intro screen. If I wanted an screen, I'd have my main view controller go ahead and present whatever intro I want. That way when the intro is dismissed (or popped off, depending upon whether you pushed or presented modally), my main view controller is still at the top (and useful methods like popToRootViewController work perfectly).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After reading your reply I updated the code and resolved the error. Thanks. I was getting lost with the scope of introview and ARC.

Comment: Yes, I want an intro screen when the app loads (only for the first time). From the intro screen the user can click on a button to log in or sign up and after the sign up/log in process I want to load a tab bar controller with a table view in it. What do you recommend in such a scenario? Thanks for going into detail

Comment: I'd have my viewDidLoad of my main view controller determine whether this intro/login screen was needed, and then present that view controller (either via modal or pushing it if you're using a navigation controller).